# Why member/2 does not return immediately

Tags: prolog

I need a predicate for whether an element is in the list. I've tried to use member/2, but I've noticed a strange behaviour.

When I call something like `member(1, [1, 2, 3]).` the SWI-prolog outputs `true` and waits for me to press enter before execution terminates. This does not happen when element is not in list.

I have two questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What would be the code for member/2 which will return immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is this happening?

The definition of `member/2` permits to succeed several times, even if the very same solution is found.  In your list, all elements were different. But consider the case with two additional occurrences of 1 at the end:

```
?- member(1,[1,2,3,1,1]).
   true
;  true
;  true.
```

> 2. What would be the code for member/2 which will return immediately?

This is commonly called `memberd/2`.

```
?- memberd(1,[1,2,3,1,1]).
   true.

?- memberd(X,[1,2,3,1,1]).
   X = 1
;  X = 2
;  X = 3
;  false.
```

The difference is easy to grasp. `member/2` is essentially defined as:

```
member(X, [X|_Xs]).
member(E, [_X|Xs]) :-
   member(E, Xs).
```

Note that these two clauses are not mutually exclusive! This is the reason why it searches for alternate solutions even if a solution was already found. In the rule, the `E` and the `_X` might be identical.

By ensuring that `E` and `X` are different in the rule, we get a first definition of `memberd/2`:

```
memberd(X, [X|_Xs]).
memberd(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   dif(E, X),
   memberd(E, Xs).
```

Thanks to this `dif/2` the rule is only considered, if the current element is different to `E`. What is missing here, however, is that Prolog will still have to consider both before concluding that they are disjoint.

The full definition contains some technicalities to avoid useless choices.

```
memberd(X, [E|Es]) :-
   if_(X = E, true, memberd(X, Es)).
```

Using `library(reif)`
for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and
[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl) this is expanded to:

```
memberd(X, [E|Es]) :-
    (   X\=E
    ->  memberd(X, Es)
    ;   X==E
    ->  true
    ;   X=E,
        true
    ;   dif(X, E),
        memberd(X, Es)
    ).
```

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for, kudos.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative answer to the second question.

> 2. What would be the code for member/2 which will return immediately?

If you only wish to check if `X` is a member of `Es` and both are ground, you can use

```
memberchk(X, Es).
```

`memberchk/2` is a [built-in in SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2), but if it wasn't, you could define it as

```
memberchk(X, Es) :-
    member(X, Es),
    !.
```

The cut (`!`) after the `member/2` call tells Prolog to forget about any other choices that the call might still have left to try.

Your example succeeds deterministically (immediately):

```
?- memberchk(1, [1, 2, 3]).
true.
```

But note that `memberchk/2` is quite different from `member/2`. For example:

```
?- findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- findall(X, memberchk(X, [1, 2, 3]), Xs).
Xs = [1].
```