# Converting if-then in Prolog to multiple clauses with reification

Tags: if-statement, prolog, cut

I want to design a top-level interface for Prolog that is not buggy (where `!` successfully cuts choicepoints, not `if-then` causing choicepoints to be buggily cut).  I thought that I could convert `if-then` to clauses where the truth of the antecedent is reified and its truth is tested to be true or false at the start of each clause.

For example, `test1` below shows the original if-then clause.

```
test1:-(a1(1)->b1;c1).
a1(1).
b1.
c1.
```

Comment: Unclear. Where is the evidence that `->`  is "buggy"? Perhaps you want `*->` instead?

Comment: I read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088097/prolog-if-then-else-constructs-vs-vs-if-3 that (*->)/2 exhibits the same problems as Prolog’s unsound negation.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you have a relatable example which also demonstrates the "buggily cut"?

Comment: @brebs, see [`char_class/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37057721/772868) for an example how `(*->)/2` does not work as expected.

Comment: Ah, the subtlety of whether instantiated. I'm liking the `if_((Ch = a ; Ch = b), Class = ab, Class = other).` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37057721/

Comment: What do you mean "buggily cut"? Since you mention it, you should explain what you mean.

Comment: With the combination of https://github.com/luciangreen/listprologinterpreter/tree/bf0d1c031dea62467d288fa2caf10a0a86e0dd1c and https://github.com/luciangreen/SSI/tree/1d011c3148fcfb6edd02292b0151fa9aa858848d lucianpl(off,[[n,findall],[[[v,a],[v,b]],[[n,appendz],[[v,a],[v,b],[1,2,3]]],[v,c]]],[[[n,appendz],[[],[v,a],[v,a]],":-",[[[n,true]]]],[[n,appendz],[[[v,a],"|",[v,d]],[v,b],[[v,a],"|",[v,c]]],":-",[[[n,appendz],[[v,d],[v,b],[v,c]]],[[n,cut]]]]],R),writeln1(R). produces [[[[v,c],[[[],[1,2,3]],[[1],[2,3]],[[1,2],[3]],[[1,2,3],[]]]]]]

Comment: but interpret(off,[[n,findall],[[[v,a],[v,b]],[[n,appendz],[[v,a],[v,b],[1,2,3]]],[v,c]]],[[[n,appendz],[[],[v,a],[v,a]],":-",[[[n,true]]]],[[n,appendz],[[[v,a],"|",[v,d]],[v,b],[[v,a],"|",[v,c]]],":-",[[[n,appendz],[[v,d],[v,b],[v,c]]],[[n,cut]]]]],R),writeln1(R). produces [[[[v,c],[[[],[1,2,3]],[[1],[2,3]]]]]]

Comment: I updated SSI so that only it, not LPI, can return all the possible results of appendz.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `library(reif)` also more complex conditions can be reified. In particular, conjunctions and disjunctions of any reified condition. So facts can be encoded as a disjunction (one alternative per fact) of a conjunction (one `=` per argument).  Of course, neither direct cuts nor a soft cut like `*->` can solve this problem alone. See [`char_class/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37057721/772868) for such an example.

To better illustrate the use of `library(reif)`, here is a correct implementation of @brebs' `member_other/3`. It is just as determinate as brebs expects it to be, in addition it is correct for the cases where brebs' implementation <del>is</del> was broken. Some benchmarks at the end show that this solution is sometimes the fastest and most space efficient.

```
member_other(E, Lst, Elem) :-
   if_(memberd_t(E, Lst), E = Elem, other(E) = Elem).

?- member_other(E, [a,b], O).
   E = a, O = a
;  E = b, O = b
;  O = other(E), dif(a,E), dif(b,E).
?- member_other(b, [a,b], O).
   O = b.
?- member_other(c, [a,b], O).
   O = other(c).
?- member_other(a, [a], other(a)).
   false.
?- freeze(E,(E=a;E=b)), member_other(E,[c],R).
   R = other(E),
   freeze(E, (E=a;E=b)).  % brebs has a redundant dif(E, c).
?- freeze(E,E < 0), numlist(1,400000,L), time(member_other(E,L,R)).
%  3,600,003 inferences, 0.280 CPU in 0.280 seconds (100% CPU, 12836803 Lips)
% vs. brebs' and newbrebs:
% 13,200,005 inferences, 1.382 CPU in 1.382 seconds (100% CPU,  9554032 Lips)
%  3,600,004 inferences, 0.263 CPU in 0.263 seconds (100% CPU, 13688070 Lips)
?- numlist(1,400000,L), time(member_other_if(-1,L,R)).
%    800,003 inferences, 0.042 CPU in 0.042 seconds (100% CPU, 18944780 Lips)
% vs. brebs' and newbrebs:
%  2,000,004 inferences, 0.203 CPU in 0.203 seconds (100% CPU,  9834699 Lips)
%    800,004 inferences, 0.043 CPU in 0.043 seconds (100% CPU, 18709716 Lips)
?- numlist(1, 4000, L), time(member_other_if(E, L, other(M))).
% 288,115,984 inferences, 14.393 CPU in 14.396 seconds (100% CPU, 20018259 Lips)
% vs. brebs' and newbrebs which is much faster in this case:
%     104,005 inferences,  0.019 CPU in  0.019 seconds (100% CPU,  5563599 Lips)
%     112,005 inferences,  0.037 CPU in  0.037 seconds (100% CPU, 3011414 Lips)
```

The major difference between both versions can best be seen with the following query:

```
?- member_other(E,[A,B,C],R).
   E = A, R = E
;  E = B, R = E, dif:dif(A,E)
;  E = C, R = E, dif:dif(A,E), dif:dif(B,E)
;  R = other(E), dif:dif(A,E), dif:dif(B,E), dif:dif(C,E).
?- member_other_brebs(E,[A,B,C],R).
   E = A, R = E
;  E = B, R = E, partially_redundant
;  E = C, R = E, partially_redundant
;  R = other(E), dif:dif(E,A), dif:dif(E,C), dif:dif(E,B).
```

So brebs' version admits the same redundancies that also [`member/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680269/772868) does. The deeper problem behind is that it seems difficult to ensure that brebs' version is indeed pure and monotonic, as was shown by this lengthy development process.

And here is its expansion for SICStus with module prefixes removed such that it can be  used also with systems whose differing goal expansion mechanisms do not produce the optimal result like (currently) SWI and Scryer.

```
member_other(A,B,C) :-
   memberd_t(A,B,D),
   (  D==true ->
      A=C
   ;  D==false ->
      other(A)=C
   ;  nonvar(D) ->
      throw(error(type_error(boolean,D),type_error(call(user:memberd_t(A,B),D),2,boolean,D)))
   ;  throw(error(instantiation_error,instantiation_error(call(user:memberd_t(A,B),D),2)))
   ).

memberd_t(A, B, C) :-
   i_memberd_t(B, A, C).

i_memberd_t([], _, false).
i_memberd_t([A|B], C, D) :-
   (  A\=C ->
      i_memberd_t(B, C, D)
   ;  A==C ->
      D=true
   ;  A=C,
      D=true
   ;  dif(A, C),
      i_memberd_t(B, C, D)
   ).
```

Comment: More and more your programming style becomes closer to the internal reif-code. So now you appreciate `(\=)/2`, very nice indeed... The fundamental difference is that I used a reified version of `memberd/2` whereas you stick with the more traditional (and faster, but also more redundant) `member/2`-inspired style. What I still do not see is how you can break down your code into parts that are *a priori* pure.

Comment: I think I added confusion by mentioning "purity" - I've removed the word from my answer. I'm treating the list as a set, and so have the advantage of immediate termination with the first `==` match.

Comment: Adding the `dif` constraints whilst iterating through the list, *hugely* slows down the comparisons. This is why `numlist(1, 4000, L), time(member_other_if(E, L, other(M))).` suffers so badly - although I get about 6.1 seconds, not 14, using swi-prolog 9.0.4 on Alpine Linux.

Comment: I'm just thinking of more important properties than resource consumption. In particular termination.

Comment: Do you mean if the list is open? The list could get closed by `freeze`, as in the example `freeze(L, (L=[a] ; L=[b])), member_other(a, L, other(a)).` - I don't think an open list can be guarded against.

Comment: ~ only concerned about cases where `ìf_` works

Answer (score 1):

Here, `test2` shows how `if-then` has been converted into separate clauses.  So, `test1.` does the same thing as `test2.`, but `test2`'s choicepoints are available to cut, as against the `if-then` clause in `test1` possibly causing choicepoints to be buggily cut.

```
test2:-a2(1,R),d2(R). 

a2(1,true).
a2(_,false).
d2(true):-b2,!. 
d2(false):-c2.
b2.
c2.
```

Comment: I could convert to the `test2` format at compilation and display if-then using the `test1` format in trace mode.

Comment: a2 is *defaulty* - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog-defaulty/

Answer (score 1):

As an example of determinism:

```
member_other(Elem, Lst, Member) :-
    member_other_(Lst, Elem, [], Member).
    
% Can be other
member_other_([], Elem, DL, other(Elem)) :-
    % Have delayed adding attributes to Elem, for performance
    maplist(dif(Elem), DL).
member_other_([H|T], E, DL, M) :-
    (   H \= E
    % Fast failure, no need for dif
    ->  member_other_(T, E, DL, M)
    ;   (   H == E
        % Certain match, can ignore DL
        ->  Eq = true
        % Unsure, add to DL list
        ;   DL1 = [H|DL]
        ),
        member_other_eq_(Eq, T, H, E, DL1, M)
    ).

member_other_eq_(true, _, E, E, _, member(E)).
member_other_eq_(false, T, _, E, DL, M) :-
    member_other_(T, E, DL, M).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- member_other(a, [a], M).
M = member(a).
```

```
?- member_other(E, [a,b], M).
E = a,
M = member(a) ;
E = b,
M = member(b) ;
M = other(E), % Loops through all choices
dif(E, a),
dif(E, b).
```

```
?- member_other(b, [a,b,c], M).
M = member(b). % Nice determinism
```

```
?- member_other(c, [a,b], M).
M = other(c). % Nice determinism
```

```
?- freeze(L, (L=[a] ; L=[b])), member_other(a, L, other(a)).
L = [b].
```

`dif` is being used, to segregate the `other` (final) alternative from the list `member`s - applied only to the necessary variables, and applied as late as possible (for performance, because adding attributes to variables slows down comparisons).

The list is treated as a set.

Performance comparison:

```
?- numlist(1, 4000, L), time(member_other(E, L, other(M))), sleep(3).
% 112,004 inferences, 0.022 CPU in 0.022 seconds (100% CPU, 5032910 Lips)
```

Versus using `if_`:

```
?- numlist(1, 4000, L), time(member_other_if(E, L, other(M))), sleep(3).
% 288,115,984 inferences, 6.124 CPU in 6.139 seconds (100% CPU, 47043287 Lips)
```

... defined as:

```
member_other_if(E, Lst, Elem) :-
   if_(memberd_t(E, Lst), member(E) = Elem, other(E) = Elem).
```

Comment: `?- member_other(a, [a], other(a)).
   true, unexpected.` so highly non-relational

Comment: `?- freeze(L,(L=[a];L=[b])), member_other_breb(a,L,other(a)).
   false, unexpected.` this is not robustness. Rather incompleteness. But I agree that it is still very fast, even compared to the expansion I added.

Comment: Added reification, to fix the `freeze` example.

Comment: Originally, I was also [into `?= /2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/772868). But in the meantime I prefer using `(\=)/2` and `(==)/2` instead. The difference shows in the example I added to my answer. However, please note that while trying this out there were problems in [SWI](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/issues/issues/124) and [Scryer](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/issues/1751). No such problem in SICStus.

Comment: Fixed for `member_other(a, [a], R).` Improved Boolean usage, removing the *duplicate* line. Switched to `==` for the comparison, because `?=` was unnecessary :-)

Comment: Removed `must_be(list...)` because it conflicts with `freeze(L, (L=[a] ; L=[b])), member_other(a, L, other(a)).`

Comment: This `( H == E -> Eq = true ; true )` could be supported by a dedicated low-level built-in/instruction. Currently there is `compare/3` which gives you a very close result. But not quite ...

Comment: Improved performance, by delaying `dif` (which encumbers Elem with many attributed variables) until the end, keeping a list of the elements that *need* `dif` :-)

Comment: Could you simply replace (in the previous version) `dif/2` in SWI by `fdif(X,Y) :- X \==Y, ( X \= Y -> true ; dif(X,Y) ).`. Could be that you are only optimizing this detail away.

Comment: That would have been a small improvement, in my previous version. Checking `\==` at the `other(Elem)` stage, is a bit of a duplicate check, given that the *first* comparison made is `==`. My current solution is faster.

Comment: The gist of your current implementation is that you perform `\=` early on. And only those that pass this test will be considered thereafter. So, ok, leave out the `\==`.

Comment: That would still be inferior to my current solution, which optimizes the comparisons to apply the (slow) `dif` only when *needed* :-)

Comment: For the purposes of this predicate, `H \= E` is the sensible first comparison, to allow fast failure. Then, `H == E` determines the action, including whether `dif` would be needed at the `other` stage.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the pure building blocks of @brebs' approach:

```
member_other_ifc(E, Lst, Elem) :-
   if_(memberc_t(E, Lst), member(E) = Elem, other(E) = Elem).

memberc_t(E, Xs, T) :-
   i_memberc_t(Xs, E, [], T).

i_memberc_t([], E, Ds, false) :-
   maplist(dif(E), Ds).
i_memberc_t([X|Xs], E, Ds, T) :-
   (  X \= E -> i_memberc_t(Xs, E, Ds, T)
   ;  X == E -> T = true
   ;  X = E, T = true
   ;  i_memberc_t(Xs, E, [X|Ds], T)
   ).

memberc(X, Xs) :-
   memberc_t(X, Xs, true).

?- memberc(B,[A,B|Xs]).
   B = A, redundant
;  true.
?- memberc(B,Xs).
   Xs = [B|_A]
;  Xs = [_A,B|_B], partially_redundant
;  Xs = [_A,_B,B|_C], partially_redundant
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,B|_D], partially_redundant
;  ... .
?- memberc(B,"aaa").
   B = a
;  B = a, redundant
;  B = a, redundant
;  false.
```

So this version has quite favorable termination conditions, quite similar to [`memberd/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21971885/772868) and at the same time has less `dif/2`-bulk to maintain. That, at the price of redundancies.

`memberc/2` can be specialized to:

```
memberc(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   (  E == X -> true
   ;  E = X
   ;  memberc(E, Xs)
   ).
```

Comment: If the list contains truly duplicate entries, then that's an *imperfection* in whatever created the list, rather than a deficiency of our code.

Comment: It all depends. Think of generating counterexamples and the like. With too many redundant solutions in the way, things might become very inefficient.

Comment: The appropriate way to define "duplicates", and therefore how to remove them (preferably efficiently), is problem-specific. There could be non-ground terms on either or both sides of the comparison, and coroutining potentially involved. Example scenario, to show potential ambiguity of the definition of a "duplicate": `Elem = a(X), freeze(Elem, dif(X, c)),  Lst = [a(_), a(c), a(d)], member_other(Elem, Lst, M).` That `a(d)` might or might not be considered an undesirable duplicate of `a(_)`, so the removal of such duplicates (if desired) should be done beforehand by problem-specific code.

Comment: As you have written it, there will be partial redundancies. But there is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33328762/772868) that still has not received a completely satisfactory answer.